# PHP Simple HTML DOM Select

Tags: php, dom, синтаксический-анализ

Кто использовал его может знает? пытаюсь получить со страницы все option коих 3 штучки, оно мне выдает всего 1 - первую, кто-то знает, как это исправить?

```
<?php
  include './simple_html_dom.php';
  function curl_to_SimpleHTMLDom($curl_content){
    $HTMLDom_content = new simple_html_dom();
      $HTMLDom_content->load($curl_content, true, false); 
      return($HTMLDom_content); 
  }
  function curl_get_page($url){
    $ch = curl_init('http://'.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    $curl_content = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    return ($curl_content);
  }
  $page_to_parse = "vitality-opt.com.ua/zhenskaya-odezhda/reglan-art-30403-belyj-10701.html";
  $curl_content = curl_get_page($page_to_parse);
  $s_HTML_D_c = curl_to_SimpleHTMLDom($curl_content); 
  $options = $s_HTML_D_c->find('option');
  print_r($options);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот минимальный пример, который прекрасно работает с вашим URL:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html($url); // URL тот же
foreach( $html->find('option') as $opt ) { print( $opt."\n" ); }
```

А выводит он одну строку:

```
<option>Выберите вариант...</option>
```

Потому что option в HTML всего одна и есть, остальные формируются динамически.

Здесь нужный select формируется одним из javascript, из него данные можно выдернуть так, например:

```
foreach( $html->find('script') as $script )
{
  $rc = array();
  if( !preg_match( '/Product\.Config\((.*)\)/', $script->innertext, $rc) || !$rc[1] )
    continue;
  $data = json_decode( $rc[1] );
  // в переменной $data нужная структура в формате JSON, дальше работаем с ней
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал вот так:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('ваш_урл_который_парсите');
preg_match_all("/<option.*?>.*?<\/option.*?>/si", $html, $result);

//var_dump($result);

?>
```

Рабочий пример тут: http://ideone.com/KbZcfc

Comment: Человек уже пошёл правильным путём, зачем сбивать его на кривую тропинку :)

Comment: Тонны никому не нужного кода «курла» и «simple_html_dom» - ну даже не знаю насколько это правильно.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в правильности и курл тут нужен, контекст вопроса я не отменял, но код вами написанный не работает на моей страничке, все-равно только 1 option вываливает...

Comment: Как с вами связаться?

Comment: Насчёт курла не могу ничего сказать. Если нет никаких специальных требований (HTTP-заголовки, например, etc) то, конечно, не нужен. Но всех условий мы не знаем. 

А вот почему разбирать разметку регекспами не надо - это сложно объяснить, это нужно ждать, когда испытуемый сам себе ноги переломает, запутавшись в своих же костылях...

Comment: Про регекспы согласен, курл для мульти загрузки страниц, так как сайт донора ложится, если просто в цикле скачивать с помощью file_get_contents. Пожалуйста не оставляйте комментарии не по теме.

Comment: 1) Прошу прощения но код работает прекрасно, если у Вас <option/> генерируется динамически, тут никак не поможешь.


2) Будто бы `«simple_html_dom»` парсит каким то иным методом, отличным от регулярок
-----------------------------------

Comment: Не подскажете, как в таком случаем поступить, если код генерируется динамически?

Comment: обновил ответ